# Matrix for orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-space, orthogonality

Given was $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} i\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\i\\1 \end{pmatrix}$.

1) I needed a orthonormalized basis $B$ of the sub-space built by $v_1, v_2$ and I got:

$B = (w_1, w_2) = ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} i\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$, $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \begin{pmatrix} -i\\2i\\1 \end{pmatrix})$

2) I was told to add one vector so that I get an orthonormalized basis for $\mathbb{C}^3$:

I choose $w_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\i\\-i \end{pmatrix}$

3) I now need to determine the **matrix for the orthogonalprojection onto subspace U relating to the orthonomalized basis B = (w_1, w_2, w_3)**

What is this matrix of orthogonal projection and how can I calculate it?

Comment: If $B$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ then $U=\mathbb R^3$, and there is no point in calculating the projection matrix.

Comment: Hi! The subspace U is spanned by $v_1, v_2$ so it's $U = \mathbb{C}^2$ or not?

Comment: So how exactly can I compute the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If $U=\{v_1,v_2\}$, then the projection matrix is \begin{equation} A=[w_1,w_2,w_3]\begin{bmatrix}I_2 & 0 \\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix}[w_1,w_2,w_3]^*. \end{equation}
This follows from the fact that for any $v \in U$, you will get $Av=v$, and if $w \notin U$ then $Aw=0$.

Comment: Hi - okay, so then I have three $ 3 \times 3 $ matrices? As a result I have $ A = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & -2 & 2i \\ -2 & 4 & 2i \\ -2i & -2i & 4 \end{pmatrix}$. $Av = v$ works fine so far. I then found a correct orthogonal vector $w_3 = (-1, -1, -i)$ and so I shoule be done now, right?

Comment: hey @Vazrael. Yes you are working with an operator on $\mathbb{C}^3$, so you must have $3 \times 3$ matrices. Think about it, if you have a $2 \times 2$ projection matrix projecting onto $\mathbb{C}^2$, then you essentially have a matrix which is similar to $I_2$, or put another way, just a change of basis matrix. Yes the new $w_3$ you have is correct, the one given in your question above is not orthogonal to $w_1$. So then using your new $w_3$ I get: $A=\frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&i \\ -1&2&i \\ -i&-i&2 \end{bmatrix}$.